# Order of execution of 'when', 'until' and 'loop' in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write an ansible task that checks whether a service on a dynamic subset of nodes has concluded, every 5 minutes and up to 40 times.

For this I've written the following task:

```yaml
# single-iteration.yml
# [...]
- name: Wait for completion on at least one primary host
  when: item|int == host_id|int
  service_facts:
  register: result
  until: result.ansible_facts.services['myservice.service'].state != "running"
  loop: "{{ primary_host_ids }}"
  retries: 40
  delay: 300
  ignore_errors: true
# [...]
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Is there a way to influence the order of execution of `when`, `loop`, and `until`?
   Specifically, I'd want to loop over my hosts first, then retry if none have finished, but only do this when the host's `node_id` is equal to the currently looped `primary_host_id`.
   However, it currently seems like the `loop` is executed first, then the `when` condition is evaluated, and afterward, the `until` loop is evaluated:

   ```
   Desired order:
   retry until one host has concluded: {
     loop over IDs: {
       when item is host_id: {
         check_state
       }
     }
   }

   Current order:
   loop over IDs: {
     when item is host_id: {
       retry until one host has concluded: {
         check_state
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Unfortunately, I cannot statically set the `primary_hosts` in my inventory since they change between executions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to influence the order of execution of when, loop, and until?

Short answer: no. The execution order you've witnessed is the expected one.

> Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Unfortunately, I cannot statically set the primary_hosts in my inventory since they change between executions.

You can add hosts to the in memory inventory using the [`add_host` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html). Here is a pseudo playbook to guide you to the best practice in this situation:

```yaml
- name: get dynamic hosts
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    # Replace this with a real task getting your data
    - name: get the data
      ansible.builtin.command: echo server1,server2,server3
      register: get_hosts
    
    - name: add dynamic host to specific in-memory group
      ansible.builtin.add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups:
          - my_dynamic_group
        loop: "{{ get_hosts.split(',') }}"


- name: Do something on the dynamic group
  hosts: my_dynamic_group

  tasks:
    - name: Service facts
      service_facts:
      register: result
      until: result.ansible_facts.services['myservice.service'].state != "running"
      retries: 40
      delay: 300
```

Comment: I've seen the add_host, however, I'd also need to remove them again/reset this.

Comment: If you need to change them during execution yes. But `add_host` works in memory so any host added like this will not survive between separate playbook run.

Comment: That's fine. I wouldn't want it to be permanent, but I have the code above inside a role and have a looped execution on the role which takes care of my parameters for each run. In this case, the hosts in the memory would not be reset, correct? Is there a way to force this to happen or re-read the initial inventory at the end of each loop?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. I don't see why you would have to "re-read" the initial inventory since it is already there. Work something out from the above and provide a [mre] to show the exact issue you're still having.

Comment: I've edited my question above with some more information. If anything is still unclear, please let me know. Though at this point it may be more sensible to open another question for my specific problem since the initial question from the title is answered

Comment: Your edit looks like bad design around an [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please widen the subject and explain which core problem you are trying to solve. Generally speaking, looping on a group of hosts or anything that looks like it is in most situation a bad practice. From the incomplete info we have above, it looks like you should apply your role to a group of host using the natural play loop and not loop over a group of hosts in your role. But it's hard to propose a solution without knowing where you want to go exactly.

Comment: I've rephrased the question. Hopefully, it's more helpful this time.